# Different types of application in web development

Tags: web-applications, web

What is difference between Web Application, Website, Web Forms, Web Farms?

Comment: This is going to get closed. But what *is* a Web Farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some semantics in this but basically ....

A **Web application** is an Internet based application, an application that is delivered over the internet. This usually takes the form of a browser based front end, some middleware implementing business logic and a back end database all working in concert.  The application  could be a piece of business logic, an internet shopping site or anything like that. The application is the whole bunch of stuff that makes the website work.

eBay is a **Web Application**. www.ebay.co.uk is the **website**, the public users interface into the ebay application and the outside worlds view of the ebay application.

A **Web form** is a web based form that a user fills in, the data of which is either mailed to someone or may be submitted into some middle layer application. A form is also a segment of an HTML browser page.

A **web farm** is usually used to refer to a collection of **web servers** ( the hardware that serves up the code that delivers the pages to your browser ) these are configured to spread the load of many public users connecting ( with their browser or client ) simultaneously to an application.